# Make blocks of similar text dynamic in HTML

Tags: html, web-services

I'm working on a business' website and I'm got blocks that essentially look like

```
<h2>Product 1</h2>
<em> Description...</em>

<h2>Product 2</h2>
<em>Description...</em>

...
```

and so on. Let's say they have 20 products. Suddenly they roll out a new product line. Is there any way to change the product names and descriptions to make the product names and descriptions dynamic so that they can be read off some external file instead of changing all these hard coded values individually?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some sort of database interface to create pages dynamically like this. Any content management system (CMS) can handle this for you. I would suggest looking at something like Wordpress (http://www.wordpress.org) as a solution.

Comment: Say the company happens to have one (but doesn't use it with the website). What might this look like?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "this" in "What might this look like?" What might what look like?

Comment: I mean how would you implement dynamic HTML pages in CMS. I know the company has one but I have never used it.

Comment: I would say teaching you how a CMS works is beyond the scope of this page. Click the link I gave you and you will find a treasure of knowledge on how to implement Wordpress as a CMS.